# register activation link in angular 2

Tags: angular, mongodb

this is my activation.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyserviceService } from '../myservice.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import {FlashMessagesService} from 'angular2-flash-messages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-activationpage',
  templateUrl: './activationpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./activationpage.component.css']
})
export class ActivationpageComponent implements OnInit {
  message;
  messageClass;

  constructor(private flashMessage:FlashMessagesService,private _service:MyserviceService,private _router:Router,private route: ActivatedRoute) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activate(this.route.snapshot.params['token']);
  }
  activate(token)
  {
    this._service.activate('http://localhost:3000/users/activate'+token).subscribe(data=>{
      if(data.success)
        {
          console.log('success');
          this.messageClass = 'alert alert-success'; // Set a success class
          this.message = data.message; // Set a success message
        }else{
          console.log('fail');
          this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger'; // Set an error class
          this.message = data.message; // Set an error message
        }
    });

  }

}
```

this is my service.ts

```
activate(token)
  {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/users/activate'+token,{headers: headers})
    .map(res=>res.json());
  }
```

i want get the backend message , My backend nodejs working properly, In frontend i get message like "No token provide". i am new to angular please help me,how to load token in service.

Answer (score 0):

From componen.ts you no need to send the Base URL, Just pass the token alone

```
activate(token)
  {
    this._service.activate(token).subscribe(data=>{

    });
```

Comment: if i put also i get same message how ton load that token.plz help me

Comment: Can you add your node js(API call) method?